# SDN4/OGM Cypher query and duplicates at Result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE parentD.id = 1 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[sortValue1:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(sortCharacteristic1:Characteristic) 
WHERE sortCharacteristic1.id = 1 
WITH * MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[rup:UPDATED_BY]->(up:User)  
WITH ru, u, rup, up, childD , sortValue1 
ORDER BY sortValue1.value ASC SKIP 0 LIMIT 100 
RETURN ru, u, rup, up, childD AS decision, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) 
  | {entityId: toInt(entity.id),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) 
  | {criterionId: toInt(c1.id),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)  WHERE NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-())  
  | {characteristicId: toInt(ch1.id),  value: v1.value, available: v1.available, totalHistoryValues: toInt(v1.totalHistoryValues), description: v1.description, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

which correctly returns 3 `Decision`:

[image]

I have introduced a new node `Tag` and associated it with `Decision` in a following manner:

```
(d:Decision)-[rdt:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Tag)
```

I have updated the first query in order to return Decision with Tags:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE parentD.id = 1 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[sortValue1:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(sortCharacteristic1:Characteristic) 
WHERE sortCharacteristic1.id = 1 
WITH * 
MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[rup:UPDATED_BY]->(up:User) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[rdt:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Tag)  
WITH ru, u, rup, up, rdt, t, childD , sortValue1 
ORDER BY sortValue1.value ASC SKIP 0 LIMIT 100 
RETURN ru, u, rup, up, rdt, t, childD AS decision, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) 
  | {entityId: toInt(entity.id),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) 
  | {criterionId: toInt(c1.id),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)  WHERE NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-())  
  | {characteristicId: toInt(ch1.id),  value: v1.value, available: v1.available, totalHistoryValues: toInt(v1.totalHistoryValues), description: v1.description, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

I have added 2 `Tag` to Neo4j decision.

The query works fine and correctly returns the same 3 decisions where Neo4j  contains 2 `Tag`:

[image]

but I ran into the following issue - I use SDN4/OGM in order to convert a query `Result` to my model:

```
Result result = session.query(cypherQuery.toString(), parameters); 

for (Map<String, Object> result : queryResult) {
    Decision decision = (Decision) result.get("decision");
}
```

and instead of having 3 `Decision` - `Result` contains 4 `Decision`:

```
Redis(null tags)
MongoDB(null tags)
Neo4j(tag1 and tag 2)
Neo4j(tag1 and tag 2)
```

as you can see - the result contains the same Neo4j decision two time.

What am I doing wrong and how to tell OGM/SDN 4 to place Neo4j(tag1 and tag 2) only one time in the result set ?

By the way - I have added `OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[rdt:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Tag)` in order to initialize `Tag` within `Decision`. If it can be done in some other way - please let me know also.

**UPDATED**

I have created a Neo4j Sandbox to test the mentioned queries:

```
http://52.87.220.140:33853/browser/
Username: neo4j
Password: idea-chocks-payroll
```

I have debugged the OGM/Neo4j internals. The following data comes with `org.neo4j.graphdb.Result`:

```
(scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper<A,B>) {rup=null, commentGroups=[], up=null, t=Node[6677], u=Node[6667], decision=Node[6678], weightedCriteria=[], ru=(6678)-[CREATED_BY,22875]->(6667), valuedCharacteristics=[], rdt=(6678)-[BELONGS_TO,22876]->(6677)}

(scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper<A,B>) {rup=null, commentGroups=[], up=null, t=Node[6676], u=Node[6667], decision=Node[6678], weightedCriteria=[], ru=(6678)-[CREATED_BY,22875]->(6667), valuedCharacteristics=[], rdt=(6678)-[BELONGS_TO,22877]->(6676)}

(scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper<A,B>) {rup=null, commentGroups=[], up=null, t=null, u=Node[6667], decision=Node[6684], weightedCriteria=[], ru=(6684)-[CREATED_BY,22895]->(6667), valuedCharacteristics=[{totalHistoryValues=0, description=null, valueType=INTEGER, characteristicId=1, available=null, visualMode=INTEGERRANGESLIDER, value=25}], rdt=null}

(scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper<A,B>) {rup=null, commentGroups=[], up=null, t=null, u=Node[6667], decision=Node[6681], weightedCriteria=[], ru=(6681)-[CREATED_BY,22886]->(6667), valuedCharacteristics=[{totalHistoryValues=0, description=Integer value, valueType=INTEGER, characteristicId=1, available=true, visualMode=INTEGERRANGESLIDER, value=10}], rdt=null}
```

There are 4 Objects(rows) at the `org.neo4j.graphdb.Result` model..

Do I need to handle duplicates at my application code or it is possible to change Cypher query or SDN4/OGM in order to prevent duplicates at the `Result` ? Ideally I need a single row with `decision=Node[6678]` and 2 `Tag` inside(`t=Node[6676]` and `t=Node[6677]`) instead of a 2 different rows.

For example, is it possible to change the following Cypher RETURN statement in order to place tags(`t`) inside `decision`: `RETURN ru, u, rup, up, rdt, t, childD AS decision` instead of having both of them at the same level ?

Comment: i have noticed that optional match do mess with cardinality AKA number of rows... try to simply add `distinct` like this.... `RETURN distinct(childD) AS decision,ru, u, rup, up, rdt, t, ,...`

Comment: thanks for your comment but unfortunately it fails with a following error: `org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unknown function 'distinct'`

Comment: put the distinct in the first place in the return as shown above

Comment: now the query works fine but with the same original issue(decision duplicates) :(

Comment: if that does not work you can also try to modify your WITH statement before with the distinct
`WITH distinct(childD) as decision,ru, u, rup, up, rdt, t, sortValue1 `

Comment: if this does not work i think it means then you have some different values for the same decision in ru,u,rup,rdt,t,sortvalue1... in this case you can do...
`WITH distinct(childD) as decision,collect(ru) as ru, collect(u) as u, collect(rup) as rup, collect(up) as up, collect(rdt) as rdt, collect(t) as t, collect(sortValue1) as value RETURN *` and see where there are two different value for a single decision

Comment: still doesn't work.. and also, as you can see at the attached images - the Cypher query works fine.. Neo4j returns correct(expected) data. Looks like it is related to SDN4/OGM layer..

Comment: ouh sorry... havent seen that... i cant help you with the OGM stuff :/

Comment: sure, thanks for the try. I have also created Neo4j sandbox to test the queries if needed