# Neo4j Cypher pattern comprehension as object property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a `Decision` node with a collection of `Tag`:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Decision {

    @Relationship(type = BELONGS_TO, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Tag> tags;

....

}
```

Based on the issue described at the following question [SDN4/OGM Cypher query and duplicates at Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117153/sdn4-ogm-cypher-query-and-duplicates-at-result) I have created the following query in order to select `Decision` + it's `Tags`:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE parentD.id = {decisionId} 
WITH childD
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100 
RETURN childD AS decision, 
[ (childD)-[rdt:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Tag) | t ] AS tags
```

Is it possible to change the `RETURN` statement in order to place `tags` inside `decision`(as `decision.tags`) instead of having both of them at the same level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure that's easy, it's then just not a node anymore, but a map.

```
MATCH (parentD:Decision)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE parentD.id = {decisionId} 
WITH childD
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100 
RETURN childD {.*, tags: [ (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Tag) | t ] } AS decision
```

This uses map expressions, where you have a map constructed by:

```
variable { .property, .*, foo:"bar", bar:nested-expression }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works,  but with this approach instead of simply get `(Decision) result.get("decision")` I have to manually construct `Decision` object from `Map<String, Object> decisionMap`. Is there any way to automatically get a pre-built `Decision` + `Tag` from `org.neo4j.ogm.model.Result`?

Comment: You could then maybe return a virtual node with APOC https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual